# Unable to use https with 1.6.6.1 version of SuperSocket dlls and SuperSocket.WebSocket

Tags: websocket

I have recently upgraded to 1.6.6.1 version of SuperSocket.Common, SuperSocket.SocketBase, SuperSocket.SocketEngine and SuperSocket.WebSocket. Everything works fine except it does not work when the client is using https to connect to my Web service.
Both http & https work fine with the older version of SuperSocket dlls and SuperWebSocket dll.

Has anyone used 1.6.6.1 versions of SuperSocket.Common, SuperSocket.SocketBase, SuperSocket.SocketEngine and SuperSocket.WebSocket with Https?

When I look at the logs I see that session was connected and then was closed by the client after few secs. When I attach the debugger it seems to call only the CloseSession handler but does not call the SessionConnect and SessionMessageReceive handlers in my code. It throws no exception or any other error log.
Does this require TLS 1.2 to be enabled to work? or any new config for tls for SuperSocket.WebSocket?

Comment: The issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing the MaxRequestLength parameter in ServerConfig.
The default value for MaxRequestLength is 1024.
You can try adjusting MaxRequestLength to 1024*1024 and see if it helps.